# How can I get around this try except block?

Tags: python, django

I wrote a try except block that I now realize was a bad idea because it keep throwing 'blind' exceptions that are hard to debug. The problem is that I do not know how to go about writing it another way besides going through each of the methods that are called and manually reading all the exceptions and making a case for each.

How would you structure this code?

```
def get_wiktionary_audio(self):
    '''function for adding audio path to a definition, this is meant to be run before trying to get a specific URL'''
    #this path is where the audio will be saved, only added the kwarg for testing with a different path 
    path="study_audio/%s/words" % (self.word.language.name)
    try:

        wiktionary_url = "http://%s.wiktionary.org/wiki/FILE:en-us-%s.ogg" % (self.word.language.wiktionary_prefix, self.word.name)
        wiktionary_page = urllib2.urlopen(wiktionary_url)
        wiktionary_page = fromstring(wiktionary_page.read())
        file_URL = wiktionary_page.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' fullMedia ')]/a/@href")[0]
        file_number = len(self.search_existing_audio())
        relative_path = '%s/%s%s.ogg' % (path, self.word.name, file_number)
        full_path = '%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, relative_path)
        os.popen("wget -q -O %s 'http:%s'" % (full_path, file_URL))

    except:
        return False

    WordAudio.objects.create(word=self.word, audio=relative_path, source=wiktionary_url)
    return True
```

Comment: *"manually reading all the exceptions and making a case for each"*... that is what you need to do. Blindly catching exceptions is never a good idea.

Comment: @solarissmoke...Only catch exception that you can handle. Not every exception. Some need to be passed over.. Or, the except block would be longer than the  try block. Use the exception to add more code is python coding  style.

Comment: There is far too little information here.  The question is, under what circumstances do you want to return False?  The reason that code is bad is that it lumps too many things together and returns False for all possible errors.  To decide how to write it better, you need to think in a more detailed way about what can happen in that code and what you want to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, exceptions come with error strings which can be used to pinpoint the problem. You can access this value like so:

```
try:
    # code block
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

You can also print what class of exception it is along with any error messages by using the `repr` method:

```
try:
    # code block
except Exception as e:
    print repr(e)
```

Comment: you can also import traceback and then call traceback.print_exc() in the except block to print the exception info and stack trace

Answer (score 0):

One way I like to go about it is configure Python logging and log the output.  This gives you a lot of flexibility in what you do with the log output. The below example logs the exception traceback.

```
import traceback
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(traceback.format_exc())  # the traceback
    logger.exception(e)  # just the exception message
```

Answer (score -1):

First your code is un-pythonic. You are using `'self'` for a function. "`self"` is usually reserved for a class. So in reading your code, it feels unnatural. Second, my style is to line up `"="` signs for readability.  My advice is to start over -- Use standard pythonic conventions. You can get this by going through python tutorials.

Throw exception early and often -ONLY when the code stops running. You could also move some of the naming outside the `try/except` block.

```
def get_wiktionary_audio(self):
    '''function for adding audio path to a definition, this is meant to be run before trying to get a specific URL'''
    #this path is where the audio will be saved, only added the kwarg for testing with a different path 
    path                = "study_audio/%s/words" % (self.word.language.name)
    try:

        wiktionary_url  = "http://%s.wiktionary.org/wiki/FILE:en-us-%s.ogg" % (self.word.language.wiktionary_prefix, self.word.name)
        wiktionary_page = urllib2.urlopen(wiktionary_url)
        wiktionary_page = fromstring(wiktionary_page.read())
        file_URL        = wiktionary_page.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' fullMedia ')]/a/@href")[0]
        file_number     = len(self.search_existing_audio())
        relative_path   = '%s/%s%s.ogg' % (path, self.word.name, file_number)
        full_path       = '%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, relative_path)
        os.popen("wget -q -O %s 'http:%s'" % (full_path, file_URL))

    except Exception as e : print e


    WordAudio.objects.create(word=self.word, audio=relative_path, source=wiktionary_url)
    return True
```

Comment: `self` is an argument to the function, which may well be a method.

Comment: I'm saying `get_wiktionary_audio` may be a method.  (The questioner may just have omitted the enclosing class because it's not germane to the question about the try/except block.)

Comment: I understand your point - But OP should state that. I cant assume OP level of Python knowledge. Could be cut and paste code outside of class.

Comment: get_wiktionary_audio is indeed a class method that is in the same class as this method I should have stated that but I thought it could be omitted